# How to refer to the input calendar popup in the calendar form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I am doing some booking form design and I want also to change the look of the pop-up calendar, which appears below the date window.

I found some free to “*use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software*” calendar, but what do I need to do to make the system display this calendar, not the system one?

My code is

```
<input id="date-form" type="date" class="btn-r" name="checkindate">
```

So, I have a free calendar in `.js` to display and know the CSS code to change the look of it. How to connect this calendar with the ordinary one?

Comment: If you are asking how to change display of browser built in calendar I don't think you can. For consistent cross browser display modify css of a datepicker script. Question is very unclear

Comment: You'll need an onclick handler on your input that then opens your datepicker in a modal.

Comment: Which calender library / software are you using? There will be instructions in the documentation that explains how to add it to your existing form. Post a link to it and we can help.

Comment: I want to use this calendar https://www.cssscript.com/minimal-inline-calendar-date-picker-vanilla-javascript/  code below

Comment: did you add the css?

Comment: Yes I did it and it works, the calendar appears on the page, but as a new element of the page, not in the place of the input calendar from the <input id="date-form" type="date" class="btn-r" name="checkindate">

Answer (score 0):

In the vanillaCalendar there is readMe file which looks like that

> ## Vanilla JS Calendar
>
> Usage

```html
html
<div id="v-cal">
  <div class="vcal-header">
    <button class="vcal-btn" data-calendar-toggle="previous">
      <svg height="24" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M20,11V13H8L13.5,18.5L12.08,19.92L4.16,12L12.08,4.08L13.5,5.5L8,11H20Z"></path>
      </svg>
    </button>

    <div class="vcal-header__label" data-calendar-label="month">
      March 2017
    </div>

    <button class="vcal-btn" data-calendar-toggle="next">
      <svg height="24" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M4,11V13H16L10.5,18.5L11.92,19.92L19.84,12L11.92,4.08L10.5,5.5L16,11H4Z"></path>
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="vcal-week">
    <span>Mon</span> <span>Tue</span><span>Wed</span> <span>Thu</span> <span>Fri</span> <span>Sat</span> <span>Sun</span>
  </div>
  <div class="vcal-body" data-calendar-area="month"></div>
</div>


html
<script src="vanillaCalendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  vanillaCalendar.init();
})
</script>
```

#### Development

1. Install dependencies

`bash
npm install`

2. Watch JS/CSS

`bash
npm run watch`

#### I encourage everyone to hack away at this!

> This isn't ready to be used in a production application out the box, it's more of a hacked together project. Fork it and make it better!

Comment: I did everything what is in this instruction but it doesn't show any result.